# Simple modules over $K\times K \times \cdots \times K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic closed field. Let $M$ be a simple module over $K\times K \times \cdots \times K$ ($n$ copies of $K$). If $n=1$, then $M \cong K$ and $\dim M =1$. If $n\geq 2$, is $\dim M =1$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple modules are exactly the ideals $0 \times \cdots 0 \times K \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0,$ where $K$ appears in the $i$th position, for some value of $i = 1,\ldots, n$.  In particular, they are all one-dimensional.